# Get the last string using a character as a delimiter in bash

Tags: string, bash

Right now I have this:

```
echo "silly/horse/fox" | cut -d "/" -f3
fox
```

But I want to be able to get the last string no matter how many delimiters we have.

So something like "silly/horse/fox/lion" would return me "lion"

Something of an equivalent to Python's string.split('/')[-1]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pure `bash` solution:

```
$ foo="silly/horse/fox"
$ echo ${foo##*/}
fox
$ foo="silly/horse/fox/lion"
$ echo ${foo##*/}
lion
```

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo "silly/horse/fox/lion" | sed 's#.*/##'
lion
```

Answer (score 5):

`awk` to the rescue:

```
$ echo "silly/horse/fox" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
fox
$ echo "silly/horse/fox/but/not/that/much" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
much
$ echo "unicorn" | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'
unicorn
```

As `$NF` refers to the last field.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to +1 yours for always finding a nice way to avoid `print`! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F'/' '$0=$NF'
```

or

```
grep -o "[^/]*$"
```

or

```
sed 's#.*/##'
```